# Error handling in Array of promises in a promise array

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an array which contains books data. I have to loop in array and make an service call to fetch details of each book and each book data has id's of attachments associated to book and make a service calls to fetch associated attachments for each book.

Here issue is if attachment retrieval fails for one of the book then it's not fetching for all the other books. How to fix this ? How to do error handling properly ?

```
function ExportbooksData(books) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let aPromises = [];
        for (let i = 0; books && i < books.length; i++) {
            aPromises.push(
                this.getBooksData(books[i].name, books[i].id, null).then(results => {
                    let aAttachmentPromises = [];
                    Object.entries(results).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                        if (value.constructor === Array && value.length > 0) {
                            aAttachmentPromises.push(this.getAttachments(key).then(fileContent => {}));
                        }
                    });
                    return Promise.all(aAttachmentPromises).then(results => resolve(results))
                        .catch(error => reject(error));;
                })
            );
        }
        return Promise.all(aPromises).then(results => resolve(results))
            .catch(error => reject(error));
    });
}
```

Comment: your outer promise will resolve once the first call to resolve happens inside the for loop - usually such promise heavy code does not need a Promise constructor anyway - you need to re-think how to achieve your result - and, at least for me, it's not clear what your code is even attempting to do (other than resolve a Promise more than once)

Comment: try removing both lots of `.then(results => resolve(results))
                        .catch(error => reject(error));` and remove the `new Promise` too - it'll probably work then

Comment: I have enclosed it in new promise because on ExportProductdata completion I am doing some processing.

Comment: well, you're trying to resolve a Promise more than once - that's your first clue that you're doing it wrong, since a Promise can only resolve exactly once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider Promise.allSettled which will allow for some to fail

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Otherwise you'll need to replace Promise.all with something that will check the individual promises as they resolve.  You may find Promise.race helpful which will return when a single Promise in an iterable resolves or rejects.